# Would higher focal lengths even work on the cheapest DSLRs?

Tags: dslr

I am interested in photography at very very small distances (10 cm) which is why I'm thinking of using a 135mm. Does this justify buying a cheaper DSLR? Or do you have to spend big money on that too?

Comment: this question seems a complete non sequitur. small distance does not imply higher focal length, 135mm is not particularly high or expensive, and lens and camera prices are orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Short distance do not mean long focal length, check macro lenses,
   Canon have from 50 to 180mm macro lens
2. Cheap DSLR+expensive lens usually provide better result than
   expensive DSLR+cheap lens